# Inorder traversal not working correctly

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write an inorder traversal without using append, here is my code

```
 (define inorder
    (lambda (tree)
      (define inorder-iter
        (lambda (tree list)
          (if (empty-tree? tree)
               list
               (cons (inorder-iter (left-subtree tree) 
                     (root tree) 
                     (inorder-iter (right-subtree tree) list)))))

    (inorder-iter tree '() )))
```

---

```
  (define empty-tree? null?)

  (define root car)

  (define left-subtree cadr)

  (define right-subtree caddr)


 tree-1
(9
 (6 (5 () ()) ())
 (18 (11 () (13 () (17 () ()))) (65 (52 (41 (39 () ()) ()) ()) (99 () ()))))
```

When I call (inorder tree-1) 
I get (((5 . 6) . 9) (11 13 17 . 18) (((39 . 41) . 52) . 65) 99) which looks absolutely terrible. What I am trying to get is '(5 6 9 11 13 17 18 39 41 52 65 99). What exactly am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems with your parentheses. Also notice that you're not using the `list` parameter - even more, it's poorly named, because it clashes with a built-in procedure.

The question requires that we don't use the built-in `append` function, but a simple `cons` won't work. Here's a possible solution:

```
(define inorder
  (lambda (tree)
    (define inorder-iter
      (lambda (tree lst)
        (if (empty-tree? tree)
            lst
            (inorder-iter (left-subtree tree)
                          (cons (root tree)
                                (inorder-iter (right-subtree tree)
                                              lst))))))
    (inorder-iter tree '())))
```

It works as expected:

```
(inorder tree-1)
=> '(5 6 9 11 13 17 18 39 41 52 65 99)
```

Comment: question is about doing it without append

Comment: @WorBlux you're right, there's a better way :P I updated my answer